# Is there a standard meaning of "low", "medium", "high" voice in sheet music?

Tags: voice, vocal-range

I started taking voice lessons a few months ago. I have one book of music that says it's for "medium high voice". Looking at some other sheet music books I need they sometimes indicate "low voice" or "high voice" but not necessarily "medium." Are there standard meanings of this?

Most of what I'm singing is between C3 and E4, maybe sometimes up to F4 or G4.

Comment: This is one thing teachers are for. They will sort out what range is suitable.

Comment: Related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/26987/ranges-in-the-real-vocal-book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My voice teacher tells me that soprano and tenor are considered 'high voice'; alto and bass are considered 'low voice'; and baritone and mezzo-soprano are considered 'medium voice.'  Note that these types of sheet music inevitably use treble clef for the vocal part, and that baritones and bases will have to transpose down an octave.  (As tenors routinely do anyway.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It tells you what vocal range the piece/part is suited to. When the piece says 'low medium' that means the piece recommends a voice within the low/medium range.

C3 - E4 is fairly low, although high for some men, many women singers are in the 6-7 category so I'd suggest purchasing a low-medium based book.

Hope this helps :)